# C code and C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, performance, compiler-construction

Does anyone know if there is any performance penalty if one compiles C code with C++ compiler?
I have a C like code and use MinGW C++ compiler. I'm using qmake to compile the project. If there is a performance gain if I switch the compiler to compile in C, I'll have to update the code, there are some incompatibility with the syntax and want to know if it worth it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is it that "performance" ranks so high in the list of potential reasons for or against a particular approach? At least once per week I see a question "X is supposed to be bad, why? Performance?" or "I got these completely different approaches which might have different semantics and probably have quite different maintainability - which one is more performant?"... (Also, if you need to change to the code make it compile under a C compiler, it's not C code. Get your language usage straight.)

Comment: C code may not compile with a C++ compiler. Surely if the code is C then you need a C compiler.

Comment: I mean by C code the fact that I'm not using OO/STL, only C runtime functions and winapi. The performance is very critical in my situation due to the fact that I'm hooking some of windows api. This is a security application i'm writing for my organization, so troll other's questions please.

Comment: I'm not trolling, I'm seriously astounded. If performance is critical, profile and profile and profile instead of asking very general (and hence hard to answer and not guaranteed to apply to your case at all) questions.

Comment: "This is a security application i'm writing for my organization" Which means, performance is absolutely, certainly not THE most important factor here (at least I really hope so). C++ isn't a superset of C, some C code may not compile with a C++ compiler and much worse: There are also small semantic differences of code which will compile but do different things (certainly not often a problem, but it still invites problems, bugs and security flaws)

Comment: @sbi: We get such questions for Java as well. Plus, Java really isn't the language you choose if you don't care about performance - then, dynamic languages are a very viable alternative :)

Comment: @Voo I already wrote that I'm HOOKING windows native apis, which has performance hit. that's why performance is a big factor for me :/

Comment: @Davita Yes but there's a quite useful axion: If a program doesn't have to run correctly one can make it arbitrarily fast ;) So I'd be more worried about possible semantical differences that may lead to errors than 0.1% more performance.

Comment: @David & Voo: C++ is _mostly_ a superset of C, even thought there are a few syntactical differences. If you try to compile pure C code with a C++ compiler you are likely to run into a few, but they are easy to fix, and it certainly won't happen if you compile your C code with a C++ compiler from the start. As for the very few _semantic_ differences: I seriously doubt _anyone_ _ever_ ran into trouble due to them in real-world code. They are just too odd. ICBWT.

Comment: @davita: It doesn't matter what you're hooking; C and C++ have the same ABI for external C linkage. There's no difference at all. Even other C ABI-compatible languages like FORTRAN, Pascal (with extensions), and many others, have no performance penalty on C API calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be very little, if any, performance difference, to the point that if there is a difference, it will be very nearly immeasurably small - assuming you're using a C and C++ compiler from the same vendor or collection. Using a C compiler from one vendor and a C++ compiler from another will likely show larger differences, but only due to the fact that different vendors implement different optimization strategies.

There are a small number of potential optimization opportunities that C++ calls for that C compilers may not natively support - but again, unless they're from different vendors, the difference will be meaningless, and many compilers implement similar optimizations in both C++ and C compiler frontends.

One exception to this is Microsoft's compiler - Microsoft never made a C compiler, to my knowledge.

Note: I am assuming that the code does not use C++-specific features like templates or classes.

Comment: "Microsoft never made a C compiler". Well, I guess Windows isn't written in C then. And what do you think happens when you throw a file with .c extension to CL? Look at the [/Tc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/032xwy55.aspx) option.

Comment: +1 To my knowledge, there is no penalty for unused features in C++. Therefore there is no performance difference. However, sometimes exception handling gets enabled which can hurt performance a bit. Microsoft does have a C compiler, but it's C90. They have no planes to support C99.

Comment: @David actually he's correct Microsoft's C compiler is just a ruleset for c89 slapped onto the c++ compiler that they have.

Comment: To my knowledge, CL is a C++ compiler that happens to compile most C code. Unless there is a way to put it in C90 mode that I've not been made aware of..?

Comment: @David: Who said Microsoft use their own compiler for Windows? But yes, there should be at least *some* C-specific code in `cl.exe` (otherwise, code like `Foo *foo = malloc(sizeof(*foo))` wouldn't compile as cleanly as the C standard requires because the C++ standard requires an error).

Comment: @delnan MS will use their own compiler for Windows, but it's probably the one built by the Windows team rather than the one built by the tools division, aka MSVC.

Comment: +1. Thank you, this is what I wanted to hear. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @delnan: Their compiler has always been extremely lax WRT C++ standards, and much code that is not really valid C++ compiles fine in most MSVC versions.

Comment: Microsoft's most recent compiler describes itself as "Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01".  They've not made a C99 compiler though, and have rejected many requests for one.

Comment: @greyfade Microsoft were shipping a 'C' compiler in the 1980s, years before they ever contemplated C++. This plus its lax typechecking is one reason for the dreaded Simonyi notation.

Comment: @David Heffernan: No, the MSVC team told me that they do provide a (custom) build of MSVC to the Windows and SQL teams.

Comment: I am told that the Excel team has always had its own 'C' compiler as well, I'd be interested in any confirmation/refutation of that.